# SQL Server 2014 - How to declare parameter which can be is null?

Tags: sql-server, parameters, isnull

I wrote code that pulls up agents stats for a date range. Sometimes some agents are taken off calls for other duties and hence can't be included in the stats.
Sometimes there are no agents taken off calls.

I wrote a dataset to pull up Agent IDs and Agent names from that table and Added a allow multiple selection parameter so I can select multiple agents to exclude them from the query ( where AgentID NOT IN ('ID1','ID2',...)

I declared the variables as follows:

```
 Declare @S AS DateTime = ISNULL(@StartDate,DateAdd(d,-1,GETDATE()))
 DECLARE @AgentName varchar(60)
```

At the moment, the code works as long as I select an agent from the drop down. But it doesn't give me any details when I don't select any agent. I couldn't make the multiple selection parameter to allow null values.

How do I write code so that the @AgentName allows Null Values?

Comment: All parameters can be null in sql server. There is nothing special to write for this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've explained better. I am talking about Report Builder in Visual Studio. When I run the report, I select the date and then I also have a drop-down for Agent name. I HAVE to select an agent from the list or else the report won't run. It prompts me to select an agent.   >>Is there a way to allow me to not select any agent from the drop-down?